# How to "test if user has"/"get" the microphone and record from it Linux, Solaris, BSD

Tags: c, linux, audio, solaris, bsd

I am trying to test if the user has microphone attached. If they do, I then want to offer the user to pick from the microphones, and then record the audio using the native C APIs.

I was able to accomplish this on Windows (winapi) and Mac OS X (CoreFoundation), however on the other unix based platforms such as Linux, Solaris, and BSD I can't seem to figure it out. I found something called `/dev/audio` is this cross platform?

Comment: You aren't likely to find a cross-platform solution except with some possible program which has been ported and adapted to their respective APIs and devices.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas. Do you have any places that have an article commenting on the methods needed to attack each platform? :)